# Query associated tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I am working to understand ruby on rails.  I have 3 tables with the below associations.  I want to query all of the items on the product table and each products associated data.

For instance I want to render in my react component:

Product Name   **comes from product table**

Product UPC    **comes from product table**

Product Availiable on date  **comes from product table**

Property Name(Ex. Material) **comes from property table**

Property Value(Ex. Cotton) **comes from product_property table**

```
class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :products, through: :product_properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_properties
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :product_properties
end

class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property, required: false
  belongs_to :product, required: false
end
```

Right now I understand getting all of the products using:

```
Product.all
```

What I am not understanding is how to get each product and the associated property and product property.

I can see [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) where they use this method but I am unable to implement this.

```
Author.joins(:articles).where(articles: { author: author })
```

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: But each product can have multiple `Property Name`s right?

Comment: Did you try `Product.joins(:properties, :product_properties)`?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Correct.

Comment: @Pavan I tried that just now and it is just giving me the products back.

Comment: Yes, you get products back, but for each product you can do product.poperties and for each product property you can do property.name.   So `@products.each do |product|` and `product.product_properties.each do |product_property|` and `product_property.value`

Comment: These won't do separate DB calls because they were "pre-loaded" by the DB join.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn  ok that helps a lot!!  Can you show me an example using that to create a json object to send to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For eager-loading, you should generally use

```
Product.includes(:properties)
```

However, the general approach ActiveRecord uses is to use separate queries to load association data which results in these queries:

```
> products = Product.includes(:properties).to_a
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"
  ProductProperty Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "product_properties".* FROM "product_properties" WHERE "product_properties"."product_id" = ?  [["product_id", 1]]
  Property Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
 => [#<Product id: 1, name: "product">] 
> products.first.properties.to_a
 => [#<Property id: 1, name: "property">]
```

If you know your records can be loaded with one query only, you can use

```
Product.eager_load(:properties)
```

which will translate to

```
SELECT "products"."id" AS t0_r0, "products"."name" AS t0_r1, "properties"."id" AS t1_r0, "properties"."name" AS t1_r1 FROM "products" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_properties" ON "product_properties"."product_id" = "products"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "product_properties"."property_id"
```

Comment: Thank you.  So I tried your solution but my query is still only returning the products.
products = Product.includes(:properties).to_a

Comment: Your query will return only the products. Your properties will be included for each of the product, see the line `products.first.properties`. You do not want to get a mix of products and properties in a single array.

Comment: Ahh. Yes.  Thank you.  That helps